# @objc selector in Swift protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I need to make my functions within my protocol @objc functions so that they can be put in selectors for my TapGesture Recognizers but I get an error that says @objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes. I made the protocol an @objc and it still gives the same error...

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please [edit] your question and replace the picture with your actual code, as text.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this : [Protocol extension on an ObjC protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980887/protocol-extension-on-an-objc-protocol) 
(I can't comment because I don't have the reputation needed sorry for the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can only declare a protocol function in a protocol, not implement it. You should be extending the UIView class to implement this protocol function.