# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime Notification never fires in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I know there are many questions and answers about this but none of them helped.
Everything is working as they are suppose to be working except this notification.
I can not detect end of video like this.

So I am using playerItem.currentTime() to check the end.
What a dayum.

```
.onAppear {
                    
                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)
                    let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: nil)
                    playerItem.add(videoOutput)
                    
                    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.player = player
                    
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VideoPlayerCoordinator.playerDidFinishPlaying), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
                    
                    player.play()
                    
                    self.coordinator = VideoPlayerCoordinator(videoOutput: videoOutput,
                                                              playerItem: playerItem)
                    
                    
                }
```

This is the notification action func in class VideoPlayerCoordinator.

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying() {
    
    print("Video finished playing")

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using a different `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(...)`.

Here is a working example code that prints `Video finished playing` at the end of the video.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVKit


// for testing
@Observable class VideoPlayerCoordinator {
    var something: String = ""

    init(videoOutput: AVPlayerItemVideoOutput, playerItem: AVPlayerItem) {
        //...
    }
    
    static func playerDidFinishPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("\n -----> Video finished playing \n")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer?
    @State var coordinator: VideoPlayerCoordinator?
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear {
                // for testing
                let videoURL = URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")
                let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)
                let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: nil)
                playerItem.add(videoOutput)
                
                let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                self.player = player

                // here
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: .main, using: VideoPlayerCoordinator.playerDidFinishPlaying)
                
                player.play()
                
                self.coordinator = VideoPlayerCoordinator(videoOutput: videoOutput, playerItem: playerItem)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it later I moved on using currentTime for now. I am using currentTime and currentTimeOld, I compare them if they are the same playing is ended.  I have more exiting stuff right now.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136455/5316027
You can just use onReceive.
Like this

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)) { object in
        //Do what ever you want to do here
    }
```