# How to changed focus field in didBecomeKeyNotification closure from SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, notificationcenter, capture-list

I'm writing a multi-platform SwifttUI app, and want to make the Mac version set the current focused field to a specific field when the user swaps to another app and then back to my app. (For completeness, I'll do the same thing on iOS.)

To do that, I tried adding this code to my view's init:

```
    let      didBecomeKeyNotification: NSNotification.Name =  {
        #if os(macOS)
            return NSWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification
        #else
            return UIApplication.didBecomeKeyNotification
        #endif
    }()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: didBecomeKeyNotification,
        object: nil,
        queue: nil) { _ in
            self.pointToFirstInputField()
        }
```

Where `pointToFirstInputField()` sets the value of `focusedField` (an `@FocusState` var) to the text field I want to be selected when the window becomes the key window again.

However, that gives me an error that `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`.

Ok, I tried to add a `[weak self]` capture list to my closure. **That** gives me an error that "'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'WordleView'"

Which makes sense since a SwiftUI view is a struct - a value type.

So what's the solution here?

### Edit:

(Note that the linked "duplicate" question is not a duplicate. I am not using the version of notifications that uses a target/action. I am using the newer version that takes a closure. My question is about how to call a mutating function from the body of my closure.)

It won't let me use a capture group to work with a weak variable either.

Comment: Note that the linked "duplicate" question is not a duplicate. I am not using the version of notifications that uses a target/action. I am using the newer version that takes a closure. My question is about how to call a mutating function from the body of my closure.

Comment: Rather than notifications, can't you use the environment value `controlActiveState` for this?

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work

Comment: The fact that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818046/how-to-set-addobserver-in-swiftui) is using the target-action overload of `addObserver` does not make it a non-duplicate. To observe notifications in SwiftUI, you *should* use the `publisher` method to get a publisher, and `onReceive` to receive it. `addObserver` should not be used in the initialiser of a SwiftUI view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work using the environment value `controlActiveState` rather than with notifications. In my tests this worked both when making the app active and internally between two windows when switching between them.

Here is a simple implementation

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case field1, field2, field3
    }
    @Environment(\.controlActiveState) private var controlActiveState
    @State private var field1 = ""
    @State private var field2 = ""
    @State private var field3 = ""
    @FocusState var field: Field?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibilty) {
            VStack {
                TextField("Field1", text: $field1)
                    .focused($field, equals: .field1)
                TextField("Field2", text: $field2)
                    .focused($field, equals: .field2)
                TextField("Field3", text: $field3)
                    .focused($field, equals: .field3)
            }
            .onChange(of: controlActiveState) { old, new in
                if new == .key {
                    field = .field2
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work. Thanks. I'd really like to have it only trigger when the app is swapped to the foreground however.